# Avoiding Local Push notification to fire after changing time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app, I want to send a Local Push notification every 30 minutes. One way is to just configure `local push notification` and fire it. However there is a possibility that user can change his time and move forward 30 minutes. In this way a cheat can be done.

I want to configure my app so that notification only occur after 30 minutes. How can I do that. My app does communicate with server and can get its timestamp but I want to do things which don't use much server resources.

Comment: you can cancel and reschedule  notification ..

Comment: @Rajneesh071 what is that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to detect a user altering the system clock is as follows:

1. When app launches, ask your server the time and note the difference between that and `[NSDate date]`.  Persist that as `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:serverOffset];`
2. Implement a method like `- (BOOL)deviceClockChanged` that asks the server again and compares to the persisted value.  If the difference is greater than some small tolerance for clock drift + latency on the synch request, then you can conclude that the clock was changed.  Do all this in UTC so it works independent of user travels between time zones.
3. Consider this:  if the user wants badly enough to fool your app about the time in order to delay a notification, messing up the rest of his phone, maybe you ought to just let him edit the notification schedule.

I can supply code examples for points 1 and 2 if you want, and if you want I can supply some @"alert text" for point 3 that will make the user feel really guilty about editing his notifications.

My original answer here.  If you choose to let user edit notifications, these methods will be key... UIApplication has a property:

```
NSArray *scheduledLocalNotifications;
```

and implements:

```
- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

So to change one, cancel it, then reschedule it.

Comment: How am i suppose to know that the guy tricked the timer and move forward in time to receive the local notification?

Comment: oh, you mean the user changes the phones's clock?  the only way to detect that is by comparing it to a clock not on the machine.  you would have to burden the server with a time check.  (you might edit the question to say user 'changes device time').

Comment: that's what I am asking, i do have a server machine which I can use. But I can't figure out the strategy

Comment: gotcha - I need to do time sensitive stuff in a shipped app also.  Will edit this answer....

Comment: right now i am recording server time. and sending notification using local time. upon receiving notification if it messes with recorded server time difference between last one and final.. it restarts the counter. If there is better way , would love to implement that